# Android - How to implement 9 patch?

Tags: android, image, button, nine-patch

I've created some 9-patch image files using Photoshop and the Draw9Patch tool, but as I tried to implement the images, it seems like a bust.  I was following this tutorial (http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/08/creating-a-custom-android-button-with-a-resizable-skin/).  Any reason this may not work?  I pasted the 4 images to the drawable-hdpi, and created a new values XML called "buttons.xml" and I placed the code in that XML file:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_normal"/>
</selector>
```

"default_(state)" are the names of the files (with .9.png extension).  And I attempted to set the background of a button to `android:background="@drawable/buttons"`

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: how it is looking can u share it?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought I had mentioned the fact that I can't get it to work, lol.  The `android:background="@drawable/buttons"`code gives me the red squigglies...

Comment: When I tried to compile and run the emulator I got an error about "Unsupported type selector in file buttons.xml"

Comment: where is your `buttons.xml` in

Comment: buttons.xml is under "res/values"

Answer (score 0):

Remember, different devices have different resolutions and **densities**.

In your case, you have put those drawables in **drawable-hdpi**, so you need device with **HDPI** density to work, otherwise you can put those drawables in **drawable** folder, so all devices *(i.e. mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, etc)* can use those drawables.

Read about multiple screen resolutions and densities here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html